# xmlns:message Tag Replacement

Tags: xml, xslt, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am using Advanced Bank Reconciliation in Ax 2012. XSLT inbound transformation has this values in file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:bsiso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/BankStmtService/"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankStmt"
                xmlns:message="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
```

It is working perfectly when xml files with values mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd"
```

It gives an error when xml files with values mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02 camt.054.001.02.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

If I change in xslt 53 instead of 54 the second case is working but is failing in first case. How can the following can be replaced to either 53 or 54 before transformation through code

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02 camt.054.001.02.xsd"
```

Comment: The two `<Document>` elements are not in the same namespace. If your XSLT handles only the "*...53...*" namespace and not the "*...54...*" namespace, the templates won't match. Please show us the template that processes the `<Document>` element.

Comment: <!-- This template populates the top level table 'Document' (BankStmtISODocument) -->
  <xsl:template match ="message:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn |message:BkToCstmrStmt | message:BkToCstmrAcctRpt">
    <BankStmt>
      <Document  class="entity">
        <FormatName>ISO20022</FormatName>
        <FormatVersion>
          <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </FormatVersion>
        <Header class="entity">
          <xsl:call-template name="GroupHeader"/>
        </Header>
        <xsl:call-template name="AccountHeader"/>
      </Document>
    </BankStmt >
  </xsl:template>

Comment: Underlying Structure is similar for both documents, but the tags are different which can be handled at later stage. I hope I have calrified it

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. Please edit your post to create examples that we would able to run ourselves to reproduce your issue. Adding code in comments is not very readable. Thank you.

Comment: For the good example XML, it looks like it's malformed or not ended properly.